# FutureBuilder with items Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have data from API

I put these data into FutureBuilder as an item, and everything is good,

but I have two questions about this image,

[image]

Question one: how can I remove the white space above the first element (i selected it with black) ?

Question two: can I marge the image with the FutureBuilder to remove the black space (i selected it with orange)?

this is my code: 
https://github.com/faress123/json/blob/master/test

thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

- Question one answer:
  there are many bottom and top padding.
  Please reduce padding and check it up.

1) bottom: SizeConfig.heightMultiplier * 8.75,
2) top: SizeConfig.heightMultiplier * 1.73,

```
Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: SizeConfig.heightMultiplier * 8.75,
                      left: SizeConfig.widthMultiplier * 4.7),
                  child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        "${widget.label} Collection",
                        style: GoogleFonts.elMessiri(
                            fontSize: SizeConfig.heightMultiplier * 3.23,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      )),
                ),

----------
case ConnectionState.done:
                            return ListView.builder(
                                itemCount:
                                    prodects[0].success.subcategories.length,
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                  return Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: SizeConfig.heightMultiplier * 1.73,
                                        right:
                                            SizeConfig.widthMultiplier * 3.64,
                                        left:
                                            SizeConfig.widthMultiplier * 3.64),
                                    child: Container(
```

- Question two answer:
  Maybe below code affect to that symptom.

```
borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(50.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(50.0),
                    ),
```

Comment: about question one: all these Paddings are not affected by my problem, I tried my code without a future builder, its work fine without any extra space, about question two, I want to display the photo instead of the backspace

Comment: If you want to do that,  image and future builder are should consist of stack.
Because Image and FutureBuilder are seperated area, cannot overrap now.